# Overwriting default accessors with options

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, overwrite, accessor

I am using Ruby on Rails 4 and I would like to know what could be the pitfalls when I overwrite default accessors. The Rails' [Official Documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html) says (in the initial lines):

> The mapping that binds a given Active Record class to a certain
>   database table will happen automatically in most common cases, but can
>   be overwritten for the uncommon ones.

More, in that documentation there is the "Overwriting default accessors" section which makes me think that I can do it without any problem. What do you think about?

In my case I would like to overwrite attribute accessors in order to provide some options, something like this:

```
# Given my Article model has :title and :content attributes

# Then I would like to overwrite accessors providing options this way:

class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  def title(options = {})
    # Some logic...
  end

  def content(options = {})
    # Some logic...
  end
end

# So that I can run

@article.title                      # => "Sample Title"
@article.title(:parse => true)      # => "Sample *Title*"
@article.content                    # => "Sample description very long text"
@article.content(:length => :short) # => "Sample description..."
```

Maybe this is more Ruby than Rails, but will be the `@article.title` calling the `title(options => {})` method or it will call the Rails attribute accessor that access the related database table column value?

---

**Update** (after commenting)

Since it seems that in the above code default accessors are *not* overwritten, is there a way to provide options for those accessors so to reach what I am looking for? If so, how?

Comment: Formatting your returned model based on conditional options is possible.

Comment: Your not overwriting attr accessors doing so.

Comment: @wurde Can you point me to some resource where I can know more about?

Comment: @wurde Can you point me to some resource where I can know more about? I also updated the question.

Comment: What does the example schema look like?

Comment: How are you representing :parse or :length

Comment: @wurde - What do you would like to know exactly? If I understood what you mean, the `Article` database table has the `title` and `content` columns.

Comment: @wurde - `:parse` and `:length` are just samples. However, my intent is to pass those as `Symbol` and use those to customize the logic in `title` and `content` methods, which methods should overwrite the Ruby on Rails default accessors.

Comment: It sounds like your passing arguments to models when it's more convenient to apply formatting methods after or choose to store values differently.

Answer (score 0):

```
@article.title #=> will call your method
@article.title(:parse => true) #=> will call your method
```

There is no method overloading in ruby if that is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Looking closer at the official documentation I see where your code diverges.
You forgot "=" when defining your method.

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.bar=(value)
    @foo = value
    return 'OK'
  end
end

Foo.bar = 3 #=> 3
```

WARNING: Never rely on anything that happens inside an assignment method, 
(eg. in conditional statements like in the example above)

Comment: I dont' care about setter methods. However, I posted another question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22239433) slightly related to this one but with "subtle" errors...