# Trouble on updating attributes when default accessors are overwritten

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, overwrite, accessor

I am using Ruby on Rails 4 and I have overwritten some default accessor method this way:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  def title
    self.get_title
  end

  def content
    self.get_content
  end
end
```

`self.get_title` and `self.get_content` methods return some computed value and look like the following (note: `has_one_association` is a `:has_one` `ActiveRecord::Association`)

```
def get_title
  self.has_one_association.title.presence || read_attribute(:title)
end

def get_content
  self.has_one_association.content.presence || read_attribute(:content)
end
```

When I find and read `@article` instances from the database all works as expected: `title` and `content` values are respectively outputted with `self.has_one_association.title` and `self.has_one_association.content`.

However, I found that when attributes are assigned to an `@article` then the `@article` object is *not* updated as expected. That is, given in my controller I have:

```
def update
  # params # => {:article => {:title => "New title", :content => "New content"})}

  ...

  # BEFORE UPDATING
  # @article.title   # => "Old title"   # Note: "Old title" come from the 'get_title' method since the 'title' accessor implementation
  # @article.content # => "Old content" # Note: "Old content" come from the 'get_content' method since the 'content' accessor implementation

  if @article.update_attributes(article_params)

    # AFTER UPDATING
    # @article.title   # => "Old title"
    # @article.content # => "Old content"

    ...
  end
end

def article_params
  params.require(:article).permit(:title, :content)
end
```

*Even if the `@article` is valid it has not been updated in the database* (!), I think because the way I overwrite accessors and/or the way Rails would `assign_attributes`. Of course, if I remove the getter methods then all works as expected.

Is it a bug? How can I solve the problem? Or, should I adopt another approach in order to make what I would like to accomplish?

---

See also https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/14307

Answer (score 0):

`update_attributes` in this case is just a shortcut for calling `title=`, `content=`, and `save`. If you're not overwriting the setters, just the getters, it is not related.

You're updating the values correctly, but Rails isn't reading the values you're setting, due to overwriting the getters to read from the association instead. You could verify this by checking `@article.attributes`, or looking at the article record in the database.

Also, your `get_content` is trying to `read_attribute(:title)` instead of `:content`.

Comment: "[...] your get_content is trying to read_attribute(:title) instead of :content." was my typo so I updated the question. However, if I overwrite the setter methods this way `def title=(value); write_attribute(:title, value); end` and `def content=(value); write_attribute(:content, value); end` then it *still* doesn't work as expected. *P.S.*: Maybe I did not understand what the point of your answer.

Comment: I don't think you did. Don't overwrite the setters. The updating of attributes is working fine, the reading back of them (due to you overwriting the getters) is where the bug is.

Comment: I double check the `@article.attributes` (`# => #<Article id: 1 :title => "Old title" :content => "Old content">`) and the database, nothing changed after the update. It seems that the assignment is not working as expected.